# Binary index tree applied to bitwise AND

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree

I was wondering whether binary index tree(BIT) can be used to implement the range query with bitwise AND (instead of the common use of range sum)?

Here is my code for the update part:

```
memset(BIT,1<<20-1,sizeof(BIT));
void update(int idx){
    while(idx<=n){
        BIT[idx] &= a[idx];
        idx += idx&(-idx);
    }
}
```

Can someone show me whether it is possible to write the code for query part? As I know, the range sum query is something like:

```
int query(int idx){
    int res = 0;
    while (idx){
        res += BIT[idx];
        idx -= idx&(-idx);
    }
    return res;
}
```

And to query the sum of `[a,b]`, the answer is `query(b)-query(a-1)`. How can I modify this to a bitwise AND range query?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible(at least using only one BIT). The reason is simple: if you know the bitwise AND for prefix `a - 1` and prefix `b`, it is not possible to uniquely determine the bitwise AND for `[a, b]` range. For example, if `query(0)` is `1` and `query(1)` is `1`, the answer for `query(1, 1)`(that is, an element with index `1`) can be any number which is not divisible by `2`.

I would suggest using a segment tree instead.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [user2040251's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26615314), in case you were interested, you could do it with several Binary Indexed Trees.

Consider a single bit. If and only if the sum in a range is equal to the size of the range, the AND over that range will be 1 (otherwise 0, because at least one thing in that range must be 0).

So you'd need one BIT per bit, and two queries per bit, so in all it doesn't work out that well, but it does work.

Comment: Thank you harold. Can you please show some sample codes to illustrate this 2d BIT? Thanks

Comment: @ChuNan it's just an array of BITs (a 2d BIT is more complicated). So you'd have a BIT to handle all the least significant bits of the integers you store, a BIT for the second bits, and so on. Each of them works exactly as you'd expect, you just have more of them now.